# How to insert to subclass without add another instance to superclass?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance, hql

I use standard JpaRepository interfaces with the classes.

I have this classes:

User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class User extends BaseEntity {

    private Long id;
    //Other Attr

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    //Getters & Setters...
}
```

Doctor:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "doctor")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName="id")
public class Doctor extends User {

    private Long regNumber;
    //Getters & Setters
}
```

I was searching and it seems that jpa/hibernate have no function/procedure for inserting a Doctor with info from an existing User.

I've tried to save a Doctor with info from a User query, it made a new User entry for the User table.

In theory, one can be an user without being a doctor, later one can become doctor.

Comment: I don't think this could be possible, since a User can't be cast to a Doctor.

Comment: The reverse is possible because A doctor is already a User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In theory, one can be an user without being a doctor, later one can become doctor.

That's true in real life, but not with Java inheritance: an object of a given type can not become an object of another type. If you want to model that situation, inheritance is the bad tool.

You should use composition instead. A User can have a Doctor role. That's a OneToOne association, that can be mapped with the same tables as the ones you used to map your inheritance, and which allows a user to become a doctor.

It's also better design, because it allows for multiple roles: a user is a doctor AND a musician, for example. Something that would also not be possible with inheritance.

Comment: Do you mean by composition an association with a role ? I mean a User having a role which could be a user or a doctor ? Like spring security roles ?

Comment: No. I mean that you should forget about inheritace, map the doctor table to a DoctorRole entity, and have a OneToOne association between User and DoctorRole. If a User has a DoctorRole, then he's a doctor. If a User doesn't have a DoctorRole, then he's not a doctor.

Comment: Thanks. I was thiking about forgeting inheritance.